# How do add whitespace in between a word in python

Tags: python, whitespace

Hi I am a newbiew learning python and i have a very simple question and can't seem to work it out.

I have built this little program and i was just wondering one thing.

```
print("Hello Sir !!!")
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another Number: ")
result = float(num1) + float(num2)
print(result)
num3 = input("Enter your final Number: ")
result = float(num3) / (float(num1) + float(num2))
print("Your final total is:", result)
print("You are now finished")
print("Have an Amazing day!! ")
```

RESULT =
Hello Sir !!!
Enter a number: 50
Enter another Number: 50
100.0
Enter your final Number: 5
Your final total is: 0.05
You are now finished
Have an Amazing day!!

Process finished with exit code 0

If i wanted to write "Your final total is:0.05" or "Your final total is:
0.05"

How would i move it closer or further away?

Thank you for your help today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add more whitespaces, you can just added it inside the string. If you want a new line, you can use "\n" in your string, which indicate the start of a new line.

Check this link to find out more about escape characters:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/escape-characters-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
print("Some string: " + variable) # Add a whitespace at the end of your string
```

if you have string with variable or

```py
print(variable1 + ' ' + variable2)
```

If you need space between 2 variables or use `\n` if you need to make a newline